# TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined

Tags: discord.js, typeerror

I am creating a Discord bot in Discord.js and I  need your "+help". The `+help` command will display an embed containing all the relevant commands. However, when I make the embed, I get this error.

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined
```

If you are curious, here is my code in `help.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    description: "Help embed.",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const Help = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("red")
        .setTitle("Command List")
        .setAuthor("Bots for Guilds")
        .setDescription("List of all commands with BFG software")
        .addFields (
            {name: "`+help`", value: "Shows all the commands."},
            {name: "`+ping`", value: "Ping-pong command: you write `+ping`, and the bot responds \"pong!\""},
            {name: "`+cheenta`", value: "Gives a link to my presentation at Cheenta Bose Olympiad Round 7."},
            {name: "`+whoisatharv`", value: "Gives information about me."},
            {name: "`+youtube`", value: "Give my YouTube Channel link."}
        );
        message.channel.send(Help);
    }
}
```

And `help.js` is being connected to my source file (`main.js`) with a command handler:

```js
else if (command === "help") {
        client.commands.get("help").execute(message, args);
}
```

(The `else if` is because there are more commands.)

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Out of curiosity, when you ask for "+help" (or whatever the syntax is),  are there any parameters?   If there are no parameters, I'm guessing the message would be null.

Comment: @ewong There are no parameters. I saw clearly that the "undefined" came from the `Discord` object.

Comment: You'll need to actually define `Discord`. Insert `const Discord = require('discord.js');` in `help.js` or define Discord when executing the file.

Comment: @Tyler2P I had it in the file `main.js`.

Comment: In that case, use `client.commands.get("help").execute(message, args, Discord);`.

Comment: @Tyler2P I actually did not include `Discord` in `client.commands.get().execute()`. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js - Cannot read property of undefined inside execute() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65740181/discord-js-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-inside-execute-method)

Comment: I did not know this about Stack Overflow, but apparently you can put a language abbreviation after the triple backtick pair to highlight it. Thanks to @T. Dirks for pointing that out!

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I don't think so.

Comment: @AtharvNadkarni, it does, as [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67584153/6126373) suggest you had the same problem. You didn't pass the correct arguments to your `execute()` method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to @Tyler2P's comment, I used `Discord` object in the `execute()` function in `help.js`, but I did not in `client.commands.get().execute()` in `main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using just MessageEmbed() remove Discord from execute as well so like

```py
    module.exports = {
        name: "help",
        description: "Help embed.",
        execute(message, args) {
            const Help = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("red")
            .setTitle("Command List")
            .setAuthor("Bots for Guilds")
            .setDescription("List of all commands with BFG software")
            .addFields (
                {name: "`+help`", value: "Shows all the commands."},
                {name: "`+ping`", value: "Ping-pong command: you write `+ping`, and the bot responds \"pong!\""},
                {name: "`+cheenta`", value: "Gives a link to my presentation at Cheenta Bose Olympiad Round 7."},
                {name: "`+whoisatharv`", value: "Gives information about me."},
                {name: "`+youtube`", value: "Give my YouTube Channel link."}
            );
            message.channel.send(Help);
        }
    }
```