# Backticks Inside Backticks

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

You might recognize me from [my earlier post today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67583870/typeerror-cannot-read-property-messageembed-of-undefined), but I was trying to expand the `+help` command to give *specific information* about a command. However, the code involves backticks-inside-backticks.

In JS, multiline strings are represented by backticks ``. However, in Discord, inline code is also shown by a pair of backticks, and block code is shown by a pair of three backticks. (Note: I wanted to give help info for `+help` itself, not `+ping` you see in the code, and the `+help` help was multiline. Hence I *just needed* to use multiple lines for `+ping` help, because if there was just one line, I could use quotes, not backticks.)

````js
if (args[0] === "ping") {
        const Help = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        .setTitle("Info about `+help`")
        .setAuthor("Bots for Guilds")
        .setDescription(`            
        If you write:
        ```
        +ping
        ```
        you get a response of "pong", as shown in the image below.
        `)
        .setImage("http://bfg.atharvnadkarni.com/bfg1.png");
}
message.channel.send(Help);
````

[the image in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6siNd.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: 50 minutes, no answer.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. What kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: Try escaping the backticks, so `\`\`\`` becomes `\\`\\`\\``

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you probably want to escape the backticks like this:

```js
if (args[0] === 'ping') {
  const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FF0000')
    .setTitle('Info about `+help`')
    .setAuthor('Bots for Guilds')
    .setDescription(
      `If you write: 
      \`\`\`+ping\`\`\`
      you get a response of "pong", as shown in the image below.`,
    )
    .setImage('http://bfg.atharvnadkarni.com/bfg1.png');
  message.channel.send(helpEmbed);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I see. I thought escaping the backticks would actually show the backticks in the embed, without changing it to code.
I also don't know how Zsolt could insert an image directly (rather than via Imgur link,) and also it still says "Info about +`help`" not "Info about `+ping`".

Comment: Anyways, thank you Zsolt. I will just ignore this part for now, because I have to continue watching the bot tutorial series. I will add the info when I finish the bot.