# Getting error "Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined" when checking user permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot in discord.js, and there seems to be an error with my setprefix command. it has the error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined
```

I saw other stack overflow questions about this, but none of them helped me. Here's my code:

```
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {

        name: "setprefix",
        aliases: ['sp', 'prefix'],
        category: "moderation",
        description: "Sets Custom Prefix",
        usage: "[prefix]",
        accessibleby: 'Administrators',

    execute: async (bot, message, args) => {

        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
            return message.channel.send(
                new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("**You don't have enough permissions to use this command.**")
                    .setColor(0xcff9ff)
                    .setImage("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/836044564158611486/836058814176034816/unknown.png"),
            );
        }

        if (!args[0]) {
          let b = await db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`);
          if (b) {
        return message.channel.send(
          `**Prefix Of This Server is \`${b}\`**`
        );
      } else return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Prefix To Set!**");
    } 
      
        try {

            let a = args.join(' ');
            let b = await db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)

            if (a === b) {
                return message.channel.send('**This is Already The Server Prefix!**')
            } else {
                db.set(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`, a)

                return message.channel.send(`**Successfully Set Server Prefix To \`${a}\`**`)
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my command handler:

```
const keepAlive = require('./alwayson')
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity("random videos on youtube", ({type: "WATCHING"}))
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.permissions) {
        const authorPerms = message.channel.permissionsFor(message.author);
        if (!authorPerms || !authorPerms.has(command.permissions)) {
            return message.reply('You don\'t have permission to do this!');
        }
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

keepAlive()

client.login(token);
```

I've tried changing it to message.author.hasPermission,defining message as discord.js, and defining member as message.author.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: `execute: async (bot, message, args)` should be `execute: async (message, args)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js - Cannot read property of undefined inside execute() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65740181/discord-js-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-inside-execute-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command handler, you have defined `client` as the bot and not `bot`, I'd suggest changing the
`execute: async (bot, message, args)`
to
`execute: (client, message, args)`